# error: Array required but String found

Tags: java

I want to print the first element of the string when each time it is entered. I used a loop to do this but the problem is that the program states this error:

```
error: Array required but String found" in s[0]
```

I know we cannot find s[0] because it is arraylist string. But I am sure you can help me to fix this problem.

```
import java.util.*;  

public class a 
{  

    public static void main(String[ ] args)  
    {  

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
      System.out.println("Enter your name: ");  
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>( );  
      boolean loop = true;  
        while(loop)  
        {  

          String s = in.nextLine( );  

          System.out.println(s[0]);




            if(s.equals("")|s.equals("pl exit"))  
            {  
              break;      
            }  
            else  
            {  
              list.add(s);  
            }  
        }  

    }//main ends  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use charAt method for first character:

```
System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
```